# Chart.js vertically symmetrical chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I have a chart made in Chart.js like so:

[image]

```
<canvas id="customer_chart" height="50"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('customer_chart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['', 'Conference', 'Webinar', 'Trial'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Pipeline',
            lineTension: 0.3,
            data: [0, 10, 20, 15],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            ],
        }],
    }
})
</script>
```

But what I want is something like this (without the numbers on the left upside down, lazy edit):

[image]

But I don't see any immediately obvious way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to take a look in Chart.js docs, you may see you can create [plugins for your chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins).
Plugins let you handle some events such as `beforeUpdate`, `afterDraw`, etc. to edit your graph before displaying it (*to add some data*) or after everything is draw (*to draw something above all*).

For what you want, you'd need the `beforeInit` event since you need to edit your chart before it is created.

By the way, plugins are created like this :

```js
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        // what you put here will be done before the chart initiates
    }
});
```

---

Now you know what to use to do what you want.

I still made an example, where I created another dataset with the exact same data, but in negative.
You can see [the result here](https://jsfiddle.net/ee71dgaw/).

I needed to use jQuery, to make a clone of the first dataset ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704)).
I couldn't make it work without it, but if you find a way, I'd like to hear it.